# is it possible to open a link from ionic cordova app from ios platform in microsoft-edge browser

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, microsoft-edge

I have an ionic cordova app, on ios platform , i want to open some links in edge browser rather than the inappbrowser or the default browser.

i have gone through a number of articles, and have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work for me.
I have also made changes in info.plist of project and added the urlschema. the code i'm using to open link is mentioned below
:

```
const browser = window.open('microsoft-edge:'+ 'https://google.com' ,'_blank');
```

Comment: Are you using new Edge chromium on your iOS machine? Is above code resides in any HTML file? Did it gave you any error or warning message?

Comment: yes i m using edge in my ios device.I m writing the code in .ts file                       
   const browser = window.open('microsoft-edge:https://google.com' ,'_blank','toolbar=yes,location=yes');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you could try the following
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/releases

OSX Quirk
At the moment the only supported target in OSX is _system.

So if device system browser set to edge